# Creating BouncyCastle OCSP Responses

Tags: c#, deserialization, bouncycastle, ocsp

I'm struggling to find information about OCSP in BouncyCastle, the examples I found online are vague at best, so I thought I'd try to ask here.

Here is my problem: I'm trying to do OCSP in BouncyCastle for .NET but I'm having problems with the OCSP response, in particular, I don't understand how to recover the response once I've serialized it and sent it to the recipient.

The problem may very well be that I'm building the response itself in a wrong way, since the way I do it is cobbled together from bits and pieces found online and pure "intuition" on my part. Here's how I'm creating the response:

```
        X509CrlEntry crlentry = Repository.CRL.GetRevokedCertificate(certToCheck.SerialNumber);
        BasicOcspRespGenerator basicRespGen = new BasicOcspRespGenerator(Repository.Data.BouncyCastlePublicKey);
        if (crlentry == null) {
            //still valid
            basicRespGen.AddResponse(certToCheck, CertificateStatus.Good);
        } else {
            //revoked
            DerGeneralizedTime dt = new DerGeneralizedTime(crlentry.RevocationDate);
            RevokedInfo rinfo = new RevokedInfo(dt, new CrlReason(CrlReason.CessationOfOperation));
            RevokedStatus rstatus = new RevokedStatus(rinfo);
            basicRespGen.AddResponse(certToCheck, rstatus);
        }
        BasicOcspResp response = basicRespGen.Generate("SHA512withRSA", Repository.Data.BouncyCastlePrivateKey, new X509Certificate[] { Repository.Data.MyCertificate }, DateTime.Now);
        byte[] responseBytes = response.GetEncoded;
    //I then send the bytes back to the client who made the request
```

The problem is that now I don't know how to get the Response back from its serialized byte[] form... there doesn't seem to be a factory/parser or constructor to get it back. There's a OcspResp constructor that accepts byte[] as parameter, but it throws an exception, I presume because OcspResp and BasicOcspResp are different things.

Can anybody help me? Am I building the response itself wrong, or is it just that I don't see how to deserialize it?? Any hints?

Thanks in advance
Master_T

Comment: @AndreiD: nope, in the end I didn't use the BouncyCastle objects, I just implemented my own. In practical terms this is no big deal, since a ocsp response is technically just a "status" flag with the revocation status and a revocation date if needed, so it's easy to implement on your own. I wanted to use the BC objects to be consistent, since this was for a uni assignment, but I couldn't make it work in the end, so screw it, just used a custom implementation. Still curious about how this works, if anybody has an answer...

Comment: Well I was trying to query the OCSP for revocation status, but it wouldnt work properly. I managed to use the BouncyCastle to query the OCSP but the results were never updated(I revoked a certificate and it would still appear as valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so old, but in case anyone looks for the answer, here it is: the BasicOcspResp must be wrapped into an OcspResp before extracting the bytes.

Creating the response on server:

```
    X509CrlEntry crlentry = Repository.CRL.GetRevokedCertificate(certToCheck.SerialNumber);
    BasicOcspRespGenerator basicRespGen = new BasicOcspRespGenerator(Repository.Data.BouncyCastlePublicKey);
    if (crlentry == null) {
        //still valid
        basicRespGen.AddResponse(certToCheck, CertificateStatus.Good);
    } else {
        //revoked
        DerGeneralizedTime dt = new DerGeneralizedTime(crlentry.RevocationDate);
        RevokedInfo rinfo = new RevokedInfo(dt, new CrlReason(CrlReason.CessationOfOperation));
        RevokedStatus rstatus = new RevokedStatus(rinfo);
        basicRespGen.AddResponse(certToCheck, rstatus);
    }
    BasicOcspResp basicOcspResp = basicRespGen.Generate("SHA512withRSA", Repository.Data.BouncyCastlePrivateKey, new X509Certificate[] { Repository.Data.MyCertificate }, DateTime.Now);
    var ocspResponseGenerator = new OCSPRespGenerator();
    var ocspResponse = ocspResponseGenerator.Generate(OCSPRespGenerator.Successful, basicOcspResp);
    byte[] responseBytes = ocspResponse.GetEncoded();
```

Reading the response on client:

```
    OcspResp ocspResponse = new OcspResp(responseBytes);
    BasicOcspResp basicOcspResponse = (BasicOcspResp)ocspResponse.GetResponseObject();
```

Comment: Wow, I had forgot about this question... it was for a uni assignment almost ten years ago  but thanks for replying, it might help someone in the future, I'll accept it on fate, since I don't have the original code anymore to test